# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError over private activity

Tags: java, android

I'm stuck with a very annoying issue, the **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** exception.

I want to launch new intent wit this code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

When i install it over Lollipop (Android 5.0) and above it works fine.
When i install it over KitKat it crashes with the **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** exception.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the log?

Comment: And you compiled for 4.4 API ?